# Filtering URL content in a self written proxy using Java

Tags: java, url, proxy, filtering

I need to code some proxy server for an assignment in my university. It should be able to display the content of some simple web page given by our professor.

Additionally it should filter the URL and the URL content, and block the web page if one of these contain one of the words in my "bad" array.
My question is, how can I perform this filtering in Java.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProxyServer{
    //Crate the Port the user wants the proxy to be on

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static final int portNumber = sc.nextInt();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProxyServer proxyServer = new ProxyServer();

        proxyServer.start();

    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting the SimpleProxyServer ...");
        try {
            String bad[]= new String[4];
            bad[0]= "Spongebob";
             bad[1]= "Britney Spears";
             bad[2]= "Norrköping";
             bad[3]= "Paris Hilton";

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ProxyServer.portNumber);
            System.out.println(serverSocket);
            byte[] buffer= new byte [1000000] ;

            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                InputStream inputstream = clientSocket.getInputStream();

System.out.println(" DAS PASSIERT VOR DEM BROWSER REQUEST:");
                int n = inputstream.read(buffer);
                String browserRequest = new String(buffer,0,n);
                System.out.println("Das ist der Browserrequest: "+browserRequest);
                System.out.println("Das ist der Erste Abschnitt");

                int start = browserRequest.indexOf("Host: ") + 6;
                int end = browserRequest.indexOf('\n', start);
                String host = browserRequest.substring(start, end - 1);
                System.out.println("Connecting to host " + host);


                Socket hostSocket = new Socket(host, 80); //I can change the host over here
                OutputStream HostOutputStream = hostSocket.getOutputStream();

                PrintWriter writer= new PrintWriter (HostOutputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
                String Input= null;
                while (((Input= reader.readLine())!= null)){
                    writer.write(Input);
                    writer.flush();
                    System.out.println("Empfangen vom Client: "+Input);
                }
//                for (int i=0; i<4;i++){
//                  if (inString.contains(bad[i])){
//                      System.out.println("Bye Idiot");
//                      break;
//                  }
//              }
                System.out.println("Forwarding request to server");
                HostOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);// but then the buffer that is fetched from the client remains same
                HostOutputStream.flush();


                InputStream HostInputstream = hostSocket.getInputStream();


                    OutputStream ClientGetOutput = clientSocket.getOutputStream();



                System.out.println("Forwarding request from server");

                do {
                    n = HostInputstream.read(buffer);
                    String inhalt= HostInputstream.toString();
                    System.out.println("das ist der inhalt vom HOST: "+ inhalt);
                    String vomHost = new String(buffer,0,n);
                    System.out.println("Vom Host\n\n"+vomHost);
//                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
//                    System.out.print(buffer[i]);
//                    }
                    System.out.println("Receiving " + n + " bytes");
                    if (n > 0) {

                        ClientGetOutput.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }
                } while (HostInputstream.read(buffer)!= -1);//n>0

                ClientGetOutput.flush();
                hostSocket.close();
                clientSocket.close();
                System.out.println("End of communication");

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing you need to know is that the line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not `\n`.

Comment: I used \n to make an extra lin, to visually seperate my self written message from the content